# why sap.m.Select not opening in sap.m.Dialog?

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to show [sap.m.Select](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Select/samples) when dialog pop up. And my dialog is opening when I press a button. So I create [sap.m.Dialog](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.m.Dialog/samples) dynamically when user press the button. Here how I create my dialog in controller in buttonPress function:

```
that = this;
var dialog = new Dialog({
    id : 'reasonDialog',
    title: 'Reason',
    type: 'Message',
    content: [
        that.reasonTypeSelect,
        new TextArea('id1Textarea', {
            width: '100%',
            maxLength: 100,
            placeholder: 'Enter a reason explanation'
        })
    ],
    beginButton: new sap.m.Button({
        text: 'Confirm',
        press: function () {
            MessageToast.show('Succesfully confirmed');
            dialog.close();
        }
    }),
    endButton: new sap.m.Button({
        text: 'Cancel',
        press: function () {
            dialog.close();
        }
    }),
    afterClose: function() {
        dialog.destroy();
    }
});

dialog.open();
```

and I'm creating that.reasonTypeSelect in onAfterRendering function as below :

```
var oItemSelectTemplate = new sap.ui.core.Item({
    key : "{key}",
    text : "{value}"
});

this.reasonTypeSelect= new sap.m.Select({ id: 'selectReasonTypeId',
    width:'100%',
    change:'handleReasonTypeSelect'
});
this.reasonTypeSelect.setModel(this.getView().getModel());
this.reasonTypeSelect.bindAggregation("items", "/ReasonTypeList", oItemSelectTemplate);
```

Here I can see the Select but there is no items in it.

[image]

Comment: I had no issues with making it work with your code, barring a few changes. I update the plunkr link. I am not able to run the url because authentication fails. This is working in local eclipse though.
http://plnkr.co/edit/wgWFNLbHqdtKkaA1TDtp?p=preview

Comment: Could you show your model's data? Here is a [link](http://jsbin.com/jolozazeru/2/edit?html,output) to your code with dummy data. And `select` control is populated correctly.

Comment: It seems I can't use the same sap.ui.core.Item for the second sap.m.Select as an item select template. I created new item template and now it is working. Isn't it strange?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you model is not visible from the dialog component, try setting your model

```
oDialog.setModel(yourModel);
```

If it doesn't work try to do it in the "onAfterRendering" callback.

```
onAfterRendering: function() {
    var oDialog = sap.ui.getCore().byId("reasonDialog");
    oDialog.setModel(this.getView().getModel("YourModel"));
}
```